# Unable to Launch Edge browser through selenium - Getting Profile Sign-in window

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

**Trying to launch Application using Edge browser through selenium. but Getting Profile Sign in Window [ Your Admin needs you to sign-in ]. Please guide me how to handle this in selenium .**

Edge version - 102.0.1245.33 (Official build) (64-bit)
Selenium 3 & 4
Note - Profile is already in Sync[ Sync is on ] when we try to open Edge manually

Tried passing User Directory and Profile Directory as arguments for Driver Capabilities but still no luck.

[EdgeIssue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQNst.png)

Logs:

```
Listening on port 57994
Only local connections are allowed
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: '4.1.3', revision: '7b1ebf28ef'
System info: host: 'A623008TCOET15', ip: '10.254.96.206', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '11.0.7'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[Capabilities {browserName: internet explorer, se:ieOptions: {ie.edgechromium: true, ie.edgepath: C:\Program Files (x86)\Micr...}, timeouts: {pageLoad: 1000000}}], desiredCapabilities=Capabilities {browserName: internet explorer, ie.edgechromium: true, ie.edgepath: C:\Program Files (x86)\Micr..., se:ieOptions: {ie.edgechromium: true, ie.edgepath: C:\Program Files (x86)\Micr...}, timeouts: {pageLoad: 1000000}}}]
Capabilities {}
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:585)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:248)
    at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.run(InternetExplorerDriver.java:188)
    at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.<init>(InternetExplorerDriver.java:180)
    at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.<init>(InternetExplorerDriver.java:156)
    at sample.IEDriverSample.main(IEDriverSample.java:38)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: NettyHttpHandler request execution error
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyHttpHandler.makeCall(NettyHttpHandler.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AddSeleniumUserAgent.lambda$apply$0(AddSeleniumUserAgent.java:42)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Filter.lambda$andFinally$1(Filter.java:56)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyHttpHandler.execute(NettyHttpHandler.java:51)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AddSeleniumUserAgent.lambda$apply$0(AddSeleniumUserAgent.java:42)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Filter.lambda$andFinally$1(Filter.java:56)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyClient.execute(NettyClient.java:124)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:102)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:84)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:62)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:156)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.invokeExecute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:167)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:142)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:567)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Request timeout to localhost/127.0.0.1:57994 after 180000 ms
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:395)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:2022)
    at org.asynchttpclient.netty.NettyResponseFuture.get(NettyResponseFuture.java:206)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyHttpHandler.makeCall(NettyHttpHandler.java:66)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Request timeout to localhost/127.0.0.1:57994 after 180000 ms
    at org.asynchttpclient.netty.timeout.TimeoutTimerTask.expire(TimeoutTimerTask.java:43)
    at org.asynchttpclient.netty.timeout.RequestTimeoutTimerTask.run(RequestTimeoutTimerTask.java:50)
    at io.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer$HashedWheelTimeout.run(HashedWheelTimer.java:715)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.ImmediateExecutor.execute(ImmediateExecutor.java:34)
    at io.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer$HashedWheelTimeout.expire(HashedWheelTimer.java:703)
    at io.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer$HashedWheelBucket.expireTimeouts(HashedWheelTimer.java:790)
    at io.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer$Worker.run(HashedWheelTimer.java:503)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a thread that might give you a clue on why it is happening:
https://github.com/teodesian/Selenium-Remote-Driver/issues/452